# How to access the views of the MoreViewController and change their titles?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

on language switch within my App, I need to access the views of the MoreViewController in a TabBar and change their titles.

Could anyone pls tell me how to do that?

Your help is much appreciated.

Cols

Comment: There is no official way on achieving that. You may only evaluate the subviews of the MoreViewController and try to find the one you plan to modify.

Comment: Right. I have tried that but I nevertheless have not found the way of changing the titles of the views.

Comment: Did you want to change the title of the view itself, or the name on the tab bar buttons for the controllers under the MoreViewController?

Comment: It is about changing the name on the tab bar buttons for the controllers under the MoreViewController.

Comment: Ow, but those are the title's of the `UIViewController`'s you provided to the `UITabBarController`. Why not simply supplying the right titles to them?

Comment: Yes, this is what I do. And it works fine for all the Tabs in the TabBar that are not in the MoreViewController. The ones in the MoreViewController remain unchanged, unfortunately.

Comment: My code for this is simple: for (UITabBarItem* item in tabBarControlleriPhone.tabBar.items) 
  {
   AppTab *tab = [tabs objectAtIndex:i++];
   item.title = tab.name;
   item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tab.image];
  }

Comment: You will need to reassign the viewControllers to your tabBarController after changing their titles or images.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that? I have used the Interface Builder to do the initial assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some snippets that might work for you. Note that all of the below is subject to break on each and every new iOS release at it is not meant to be done.

---

Customizing the More view title as itself as well as the title while it is being edited by the user.

```
- (void)customizeTitleViewWithNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)navigationItem
{
    VASSERT(navigationItem != nil, @"invalid navigationItem supplied", navigationItem);
    UILabel *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
    titleView.text = navigationItem.title;
    [titleView sizeToFit];
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
    [titleView release];
}
```

This needs to be implemented within the `UINavigationController`'s delegate;

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (navigationController == tabBarController_.moreNavigationController)
    {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIMoreListController")])
        {
            [self customizeTitleViewWithNavigationItem:viewController.navigationItem];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"viewController (%@) does not seem to be a UIMoreListController", viewController);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"navigationController (%@) does not seem to be the moreNavigationController", navigationController);
    }
}
```

This needs to be implemented within the `UITabBarController`'s delegate;

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers 
{
    //get the second view of the upcoming tabbar-controller
    UIView *editView = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    //did we get what we expected, which is a UITabBarCustomizeView?
    if (editView != nil && [editView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarCustomizeView")])
    {   //yes->get the navigation-view
        UIView *navigationView = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        //is that a navigationBar?
        if (navigationView != nil && [navigationView isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
        {   //yes->...
            UINavigationBar *navigationBar = (UINavigationBar *)navigationView;
            [self customizeTitleViewWithNavigationItem:navigationBar.topItem];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"the navigationView (%@) does not seem to be a navigationBar", navigationView);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the editView (%@) does not seem to be a UITabBarCustomizeView", editView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the title of one of the tabBar items for my 6th view controller (the last one in the more list) with the following code:

```
NSArray *vcs = [(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers];
[[vcs.lastObject tabBarItem] setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

Is this what you want to do?

After Edit:  To change these titles after they are set up the first time, you need to re-set the viewControllers property of the tabBar controller. In this code example, I connected a button in my 6th view controller to an action method that changes the titles of 3 of my controllers, 2 in the more list and one in the regular list.

```
  -(IBAction)changeNames:(id)sender {
    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController;
    NSArray *vcs = tbc.viewControllers;
    [[vcs.lastObject tabBarItem] setTitle:@"New Title"];
    [[[vcs objectAtIndex:4] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"New VC"];
    [[[vcs objectAtIndex:3] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"New VC2"];
    tbc.viewControllers = tbc.viewControllers;
}
```

Comment: Hmm...don't know what to say, I see all my view controllers in vcs

Comment: Yes, that is right. But for some reason, the vcs contains 0 elements despite the fact that I see 4 items below "More". Where did you put your code?

Comment: it works for me in the app delegate. But later on, it does not work. I need to do it later on, when the user decides to switch the language in the app.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to do this in a button click handler of the 6th view controller.

Comment: could you pls try if it works for you if the code is in a button click handler of the 6th view controller?

Comment: @user1006117, see my edited answer, I think this does what you want.